# Django - how to download a file

Tags: python, django, download

I am trying to create a download button in my template for a CSV file generated by my website (I am new to Django). I have created the view function and updated `urls.py` but I get

> 'DoesNotExist: Page matching query does not exist'

when I input the URL ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/download_table'). I'd also like to know how to create a link/button to the download in my HTML template.

views.py:

```py
def download_csv(request):
    table_selected = request.POST.get('Table_select')
    index_of_table_selected = int(re.search(r'\d+$', table_selected).group())
    result_json_selected = request.session.get('result', 'missing')[index_of_table_selected]
    dataframe_selected = pd.read_json(result_json_selected)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'Table.csv'
    dataframe_selected.to_csv(path_or_buf=response, sep=';', float_format='%.2f', index=False, decimal=",")

    return response
```

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, {'pagename': ''}, name='home'),
    path('<str:pagename>', views.index, name='index'),
    path('download_table/', views.download_csv, name='download_csv'),]
```

Also, what do I put in my template? Something like this?

```html
<a href="download_table/" download> Download File</a>
```

That link returns the error

> TypeError: download_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'filepath'

Comment: use `download_csv(request, **kwargs)` and print the `kwargs`, You'll understand

Comment: It says `{'filepath': 'download_table'}`. What do I do? Sorry I am new to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting 404 because This is the 'app' level `urls.py`, You need to link it to the 'project' level `urls.py`

The second error is because `download_csv(request)` should be `download_csv(request, filepath)` or better yet, use `download_csv(request, **kwargs)` 
It says it got an argument (e.g `localhost:8000/argument/` ) and you have no variable to contain it.

Comment: I think it is linked to the project level `urls.py`, I have this: `urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('ReadABS.urls'))
]`

Comment: Ah okay I got it working now thank you! There were 2 problems (but not with urls.py). 1 was adding **kwargs (which got me part of the way, the error message changed then), the next issue was with `table_selected = request.POST.get('Table_select')`. Apparently that post request doesn't work in this view function (no idea why but whatever), but I saved 'table_selected' to the session from my other function view using `request.session = ` then I was able to get that data into this view function. Anyway it works now. Half a day spent scratching my head on that one! Thanks

Comment: Use `if request.method == 'POST'`, or use CBVs, learn about them [in this awesome guide](https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/)